# geometry question

Tags: geometry

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxiwP.png)

How to find the value of $(x,y)$ if

- $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are known.
- Length of the perpendicular base is also known.

[image]

Comment: so 10 is the distance between $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x,y)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please format maths with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I have detailed my explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the slope of the line segment from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$.  The slope of the perpendicular segment is the negative reciprocal.  Use the point-slope formula for the line segment to $(x,y)$ and the distance $10$ as a pair of simultaneous equations to get $(x,y)$

Answer (score 0):

Orthogonality of vectors $\binom{x-x_1}{y-y_1}$ and $\binom{x_2-x_1}{y_2-y_1}$
gives a first equation  (dot product = zero) :

$$\tag{1}(x-x_1)(x_2-x_1)+(y-y_1)(y_2-y_1)=0$$

Length constraint :

$$\tag{2}\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}=10 \iff (x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=100$$

gives a second equation.

Make $y$ the subject of equation (1):

$$\tag{3}y=y_1-A(x-x_1) \ \ \text{with} A \ \text{defined by} \ \ A:=(x_2-x_1)/(y_2-y_1)$$

Plug this expression of $y$ into (2). You will get a quadratic equation in variable $x$. This equation has in general two solutions (do you see why there are two solutions?). Once you have this/these solutions, plug them in (3) to obtain the value(s) of $y$.

Remark: please note that (3) is valid only if $y_1 \neq y_2$. If $y_1=y_2$, the segment line joining $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is horizontal ; thus the other segment is vertical, giving the evident solution $x=x_1$ and $y=y_1 \pm 10$.